Running multiple IP-based webserver on single domain
I need to run three different IP-based webservers under a single domain (mycompany.com) with vhost on Apache 2.4.
192.168.0.1 (mycompany.com)
192.168.0.2 (sales dept.)
192.168.0.3 (finance dept.)
192.168.0.4 (manufacture dept.)
How can I set vhost to use a sub-site to access each department's webserver? (e.g., www.mycompany.com/sales, www.mycompany.com/finance etc.)

set up dns and use sales.example.org etc as a vhosts. otherwise using a alias and proxy it. but this is a basic administrative process and you have to show what you have done sofar to solve it

Why do you want IP based vhosting? Name based is far easier, more flexible and better practice. To me this reads as a educational exercise, not a real world problem.
